# where is the problem in jquery code. it execute alert two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The following jquery codes alert the 123 twice.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var _product_id = 123;
    
    alert(_product_id);

 });
});
```

the form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="f-1" class="single-product-editor-form">
 <span>
    <button class="single-edit" id="<?php echo $row_no; ?>" type="submit">ویرایش</button>
 </span>
</form>
```

where is problem?

Comment: I do not see form class and you have used .form

Comment: @techie_questie I remove .form

Comment: I think you loaded your script file twice. If you load it one time, it works well: https://jsfiddle.net/qL53yo7v/. If you load you it twice, you will see two alerts: https://jsfiddle.net/wa9oudhz/.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen oh yes. thak you. :) I call it twice :P

Comment: Ah awesome, then I will post that as an answer :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you loaded your script file twice, because the code looks fine to me. As you use PHP, it could be an accidental repeated [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), so you end up with two script tags:

```
<script>
  // your JavaScript code
</script>
<script>
  // your JavaScript code
</script>
```

I did a little test:

- If you load it one time, it works well: [jsfiddle.net/qL53yo7v](https://jsfiddle.net/qL53yo7v).
- If you load you it twice, you will see two alerts: [jsfiddle.net/wa9oudhz](https://jsfiddle.net/wa9oudhz).